# Add entries of a table into rows of another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables

table a:

```
ID   VALUE_z
1    41
2    32
3    51
```

table b:

```
ID   TYPE z
1    a    10
1    b    15
1    c    20
2    a    12
2    b    8
2    c    5
3    a    21
3    b    4
3    c    2
```

I want to add the rows from table a to the column `VALUE` in table b based on the `ID`. The result should look like this

table result:

```
ID   TYPE VALUE
1    a    10
1    b    15
1    c    20
1    z    41
2    a    12
2    b    8
2    c    5
2    z    32
3    a    21
3    b    4
3    c    2
3    z    51
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following using `INSERT INTO SELECT` Statement:

```
insert into tableB
select ID, 'z', VALUE_z
from tableA
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/sBBbl0fk)